# How to separate selected column from .CSV file and save those in new .csv file with header file in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

I want to read the `CSV`file and those selected columns with headers are save in another new `CSV.

*I want to add following requirement for my code.*please help me to add these for my code.

In here I consider this requirements;
`Age >=25 && Marks0 ==True` save in this name `Pass.csv` with under header column in this .csv file `(Index,Age,Marks0)`

other requirement is `Age >=20 && Age <=25 & Marks1 ==False` save in this name `General.csv` with under header column in this .csv file `(Index,Age,Marks0,Marks1)`

others are save in `Ignore.csv` with headers `(Index,Age,Marks0,Marks1,Marks2,Marks3)`

this is my sample `.CSV` file

```
Index,Age,Marks0,Marks 1,Marks2,Marks3
1,22,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
2,30,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
3,19,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
4,25,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
5,22,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
6,26,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
7,27,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
8,29,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
9,25,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
10,22,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
11,23,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
```

I created a class to store my column values

```
class Marks

    {
        public int Index { get; set; } // property to  store Index
        public int Age { get; set; } // property to store Age 
        public bool Marks0 { get; set; } // property to store Marks0 
        public bool Marks01 { get; set; } // property to store Marks01 
        public bool Marks2 { get; set; } // property to store Marks2 
        public bool Marks3 { get; set; } // property to store Marks3

    }
```

Code for reading `.CSV` file as follows;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
               List<Marks> Observing1 = new List<Marks>(); // List to store all available Marks objects from the CSV
                Marks statusInt = new Marks();
                // Loops through each lines in the CSV
                foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(OutputFilePath.Text).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
                {
                    // here line stands for each line in the CSV file

                    string[] InCsvLine = line.Split(',');
                    statusInt.Index=int.Parse(InCsvLine[0]); 
                    statusInt.Age=int.Parse(InCsvLine[1]);      
                    statusInt.Mark0 = (InCsvLine[2] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
                    statusInt.Mark1 = (InCsvLine[3] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
                    statusInt.Mark2 = (InCsvLine[4] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
                    statusInt.Mark3 = (InCsvLine[5] == "TRUE" ? true : false);

                }

    }
```

Please give any help for solve my problem.

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: In each iteration of the foreach, create a new `Marks` object, fill it with line contents and then add it to `Observing1`. Then you can filter as you wish and write the filtered lists to other files.

Comment: @Fabiano,Sorry for that.I edit my question again sir.

Comment: @Fildor,Sir I am a beginner for this language,If you can please give me a example for that.thank you.

Comment: Please see my answer. It is not a complete spoiler but I think it will give you enough hints to enable you to move on. You are almost there, actually.

Comment: @Fildor,thank you for your support ,I will try your path

Answer (score 1):

I find multiple questions, but to get you started you can seperate columns from csv like this:

```
        var recordsToSaveInPassFile = new List<Class>();
        var recordsToSaveInGeneralFile = new List<Class>();

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\data.csv", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var items = line.Split(';');

            int parsedAge;

            if (int.TryParse(items[0], out parsedAge))
            {
                if(parsedAge > 24)
                {
                   var recordToPass = new Class
                   {
                    Age = items[0],
                    item2 = items[1]
                   };

                   recordsToSaveInPassFile.Add(recordToPass);
                }
                else if(parsedAge > 19)
                {
                   var recordToGeneral = new Class
                   {
                    Age = items[0],
                    item2 = items[1]
                    };

                   recordsToSaveInGeneralFile.Add(recordToGeneral);
                }

                continue;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($@"'{line}': could not be parsed");
        }
```

This can be done much more nicer, but this might give you an idea of how to check for different values from your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

What I was talking about in the comment:

```
List<Marks> Observing1 = new List<Marks>(); // List to store all available Marks objects from the CSV
// Marks statusInt = new Marks(); <<<<<< Move into loop!
// Loops through each lines in the CSV
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(OutputFilePath.Text).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
{
    var statusInt = new Marks();

    // here line stands for each line in the CSV file
    string[] InCsvLine = line.Split(',');
    statusInt.Index=int.Parse(valuesInCsvLine[0]); 
    statusInt.Age=int.Parse(valuesInCsvLine[1]);      
    statusInt.Mark0 = (InCsvLine[2] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
    statusInt.Mark1 = (InCsvLine[3] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
    statusInt.Mark2 = (InCsvLine[4] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
    statusInt.Mark3 = (InCsvLine[5] == "TRUE" ? true : false);

    // Add your result to the List!
    Observing1.Add(stsusInt);
}

// Now you can filter as you wish
var filteredByAge = Observing1.Where( x => x.Age > 25 ).ToList();

// Writing to a new File is left as assignment for OP
```